# Customizing navigation bar without affecting other view controllers in hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar customization problem to overcome, hopefully someone has wanted this same behaviour before.

In my navigation stack there are specific view controllers that I want to have a totally transparent navigation bar, I use this code to do it:

```
// Make navigation bar transparent
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The problem is when I 'pop' back to my root view controller its navigation bar is transparent now too, and I don't want that. I need a way to only customize the nav bar in a specific view controller without messing it up totally for other view controllers.

Note: UIAppearance whenContainedIn will not work, and this is currently styled in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Just create your new custom `UINavigationController` when you push to specific `UIViewController`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further into what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to the new style in `viewWillAppear` and revert to old or default style in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` or `viewDidUnload`' whichever suits your app.

Comment: But If I remove all the images and stuff, how I can revert back? Doesn't that permanently screw it up?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your case you could use the method [appearanceWhenContainedIn](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:)
 of the UIApparence protocol.

This would allow for a per container control of the UINavigationBar appearance.

Comment: I need it on a view controller basis, not a navigation controller basis. I don't believe  appearanceWhenContainedIn will work in this case :(

Comment: You can use it to customise the appearance for each container, meaning that each specific UIViewController/UINavigationController can have it's own navigationBar. I don't know how architecturally good is, but if you have a specific classs for the containers that have the custom nvigation bar, it should work.

Comment: Are you able to show me a code snippet because I still don't see how you can do it for a view controller basis...keep in mind that I want to make it totally transparent than put it back to normal.